# Selecting the Default value of Cascading Dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I just want to ask how can I select the default value of the 2nd / Cascading dropdown onchange of the 1st Dropdown list?
I want to select `[Please Select Location]` when the Position Dropdown is changed
  i tried this method but error says `select is undefined`

```
  var dropdownlist = $("#ddlLocation").data("kendoDropDownList");
                dropdownlist.select(function (dataItem) {
                    return dataItem.symbol === "[Please Select Location]";
                });
```

This is my set of codes:

```
var userId = $("#hiddenUser").val();
    $("#PositionInputs").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "ID",
        index: 0,
        autoBind: false,
        change: function () {
            var value = this.value();
            var dataItem1 = this.dataItem(this.select());
            if (value) {
                var dropdownlist = $("#ddlLocation").data("kendoDropDownList");
                dropdownlist.select(function (dataItem) {
                    return dataItem.symbol === "[Please Select Location]";
                });

            }
        },
        optionLabel: "[Please Select Position]",
        template: '<h5>${ data.Name }</h5>',
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '/Profile/LoadDropdownList?userId=' + userId,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"

                }
            }
        }

    });


    //kendo dropdown
    $("#ddlPosition").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "ID",
        autoBind: false,
          optionLabel: {
              Name: "[Please Select Position]",
              ID: "0"
    },
        //   define custom template
        template:
                                   '<h5>${ data.Name }</h5>',
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '/Profile/LoadDropdownList?userId=' + userId,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"
                }
            }
        }
    });



    //kendo dropdown
    $("#ddlLocation").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "Address",
        dataValueField: "Id",
        autoBind: false,
        optionLabel: "[Please Select Position]",
        //   define custom template
        template: '<h5>${ data.Address }</h5>',
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '/Profile/LoadLocationDropdownList?userId=' + userId,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"
                }
            }
        }

    });




    $("#LocationInputs").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "Address",
        dataValueField: "Id",
        //                    index: 0,
        autoBind: false,
        cascadeFrom: "PositionInputs",
        optionLabel: {
            Address: "[Please Select Position]",
            Id: "0"
        },
        template: '<h5>${ data.Address }</h5>',
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '/Profile/LoadLocationDropdownList?userId=' + userId,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: By default it will select first item, please check '$("#ddlLocation").data("kendoDropDownList").value();' after and before selecting value from the first dropdoenlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've used selects the item if its text is equal to "[Please Select Location]" but the location drop down defined here is set to "[Please Select Position]".

If making that change does not work, you could try setting the index (assumes placeholder has index 0):

```
var ddl = $("#someId").data("kendoDropDownList");
ddl.select(0)
```

Comment: Thanks sir . . Tried this and found out that I'm pinpointing in the wrong id. Changed it to LocationInputs and your `ddl.select(0)` and it's working